# What's meaning of CPS in jenkins. what's the full name of CPS?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

What's meaning of CPS in jenkins. what's the full name of CPS ?

Answer (score 13):

Continuation Passing Style

> Continuation Passing Style (CPS) is a style of programming in which the remainder of the program is passed explicitly as a parameter, as opposed to that being handled implicitly represented as call stack.

[Kohsuke Kawaguchi on *Basics of Continuation Passing Style*](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/doc/cps-basics.md)